# How to add JSP in a Maven project in Eclipse

Tags: jsp, maven, web-applications

I am working on a Maven project(Webapp archtype) which has a default index.jsp included. I want to add more JSPs. How to do so?

Comment: Just put you jsp files aside.

Answer (score 0):

To create new JSP file just Right Click on the folder and select "New" -> "JSP File"

[image]

You can learn more about Maven project structures here:

http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-web-application-project-with-maven/

http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/2/JSP-Hello-World-Program-using-Eclipse-IDE-and-Tomcat-web-server